# Vue.js - Is Chaining Form Input Modifiers Allowed?

Tags: vue.js

The Vue.js ecosystem comes with some handy modifiers for use with form inputs.

```
<input v-model.lazy="msg">

<input v-model.trim="msg">

<input v-model.number="msg">
```

I was wondering if it were possible to chain such modifiers, perhaps something like this:

```
<input v-model.lazy.trim="msg">
```

If not, has anyone any experience of making their own modifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can make custom modifiers the moment, there's some desire for the feature [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3666). Your best option IMO is to make a custom component and then emit the modified value based on what you need.

I made a quick app (included below) to test chaining modifiers and it does work.

```js
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
   },
   computed: {
      len: function() {
         return this.message.length;
      }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input type="text" v-model.lazy.trim="message" />
  <span style="background:yellow">{{ message }}</span>
  <span>{{len}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, yes - awesome. It does work - I think I was using it whilst there were other errors going on! :facepalm: Thank you so much. That's how I am currently working it - with custom computed properties: https://codepen.io/michealjroberts/pen/yLNOWeK

Comment: Looks good. If you're using a lot I would suggest separating it into smaller components to make it simpler. I had a go at reducing the computed properties which almost works: https://codepen.io/Shoejep/pen/QWbEdyZ

Comment: Yeh that's useful, helps with the two way value binding issue I was having for year and day as well. Can add watchers too. Nice.

Comment: I personally try to avoid using watchers, there's normally a neater way by using computed properties: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: Yes, but I think I will need them for user input - there's not just the option of +/- the date/month/year

Comment: I'm not sure your implentation works well either, because I go from 29th February to 30th March. Not great.

Comment: Ahh okay. Yes, it needs a little bit extra work (I should have put more emphasis on almost works)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208036/discussion-between-shoejep-and-wind-up-lord-vexxos).